# How to install the same version of NPM and Node across many machines

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-17.10

I have many machines (VMs actually) running 17.10 and I want to install a known Node and npm executable on each one. I have a script and if I run it over the next 6 months or even a year, I'd like to get the exact same version of Node and NPM on all the machines.

I tried using the apt packages but as those were updated, I got different versions on later installations vs the earlier installations. I want them all to be identical.

I tried this:

```
NVERS=v8.9.2
sudo rm -rf node-$NVERS-linux-x64
sudo rm -f node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/$NVERS/node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz

sudo cp node-$NVERS-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
sudo cp node-$NVERS-linux-x64/bin/npm  /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Node worked fine:

```
node -v
v8.9.2
```

but npm failed:

```
$ npm -v
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/bin/npm:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

The npm executable is actually a soft link to a relative directory inside of the tarball.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: use nvm to install same version across any machine. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only copy the binary file, and that is why your `npm` fails, which actually tries to look for other files inside the extraced tarball. I think the safer way is to make use of a symbolic (soft) link (Modified the last 4 lines of your code):

```
NVERS=v8.9.2
sudo rm -rf node-$NVERS-linux-x64
sudo rm -f node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/$NVERS/node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-$NVERS-linux-x64.tar.xz /usr/local/lib  # Extracting under Root
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node-$NVERS-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node # Symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node-$NVERS-linux-x64/bin/npm  /usr/local/bin/npm # Symlink
```

There is no one de facto standard way to do with npm installation in my opinion, even if you use a wrapper tool from [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) or `nvm`. My most convinced way for this is to do just by yourself, as you are doing.